# использование split('\t') для разбиения строки из файла txt в python 3

Tags: python, list

есть код, который берёт текст, в котором набор строк, в каждой из которых написано: класс, имя, рост. Всё разделено табами.
Код на 8 строчке должен разбивать по очереди каждую строку с помощью split по tab, но выдаёт ошибку 
dict[int(str[0])] = [int(str[2])]
IndexError: list index out of range

```
with open('down.txt') as txt:
dict = {}
count = sum(1 for line in txt)
for i in range(count):
    str = txt.readline().split('\t')
    print(str)
    if str[0] not in dict.keys():
        dict[int(str[0])] = [int(str[2])]
    else:
        dict[int(str[0])].append(int(str[2]))
    for i in range(1, 12):
        if i in dict.keys():
            print(i, sum(dict[i]) / len(dict[i]))
        else:
            print(i, '-')
```

подскажите, может я неправильно читаю строки или разбиваю их?

Comment: вставилось по отступа некорректно, но да ладно, вроде понятно

Comment: можете привести пример файла, который поможет воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: @MaxU, не получается вставить нормально, но в каждой строчке одна фамилия между 2мя цифрами, всё разделено табами. Вот пример: 2 Salisburry 131
10 Mason 167
3 Roger 131
8 Fraser 163
3 Marlow 136
11 Mercer 173
8 Carter 164
1 Wainwright 120
7 Adrian 165
10 Fitzgerald 175
3 Oakman 130
6 Black 155
1 Ralphs 125
6 Howard 150
8 Boolman 161
10 Blomfield 168
4 Addington 145
8 Hawkins 162
1 Longman 127
3 Bawerman 132